# JSON Parsing not working using Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

```
Alamofire.request(some_url, method: .post, parameters: data, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON{
        response in

        let json = JSON(response.result.value)
        //here print json works perfectly fine.



        self.str = json[0]["EventDescription"].stringValue
        self.cstr = json[0]["EventRules"].stringValue
        self.imgurl = json[0]["EventImageUrl"].stringValue

        //these statements are not been executed.

        print(self.cstr)
        print(self.str)
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you please post your json?

Comment: When it's not working, instead of doing various stuff one one line, cut it piece by piece: `json[0]["EventDescription"].stringValue` is too much work in one line. `json[0]` is even returning something? Is your JSON an array at top level? Could be interesting to show us the JSON.